# Google Maps jQuery Marker not Displaying

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm using the Google Map API with jQuery to make a very simple map. I've put the marker in, but it's not showing up at all. Very confused!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var image = 'www.franhaines.co.uk/thebellinn/wp-content/themes/starkers-master/images/marker.png';
 
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  title: "We are here",
  map: map,
        icon: image
    });
 
 var myLatLng = 
  new google.maps.LatLng(52.780761, -2.199389);
  
 var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: myLatLng
  };
  
 var map = new google.maps.Map($('#mapCanvas').get(0), mapOptions);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the URL of your marker isn't correct, should be (with the correct protocol):

```
'http://www.franhaines.co.uk/thebellinn/wp-content/themes/starkers-master/images/marker.png';
```

2. You are creating the marker (using a `map` property) before the maps is initialized.  Working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var image = 'http://www.franhaines.co.uk/thebellinn/wp-content/themes/starkers-master/images/marker.png';

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.780761, -2.199389);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatLng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map($('#mapCanvas').get(0), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        title: "We are here",
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });

});
```

```css
html, body, #mapCanvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapCanvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```